# Error trying to run pdfquery example

Tags: python

I just installed pdfquery in my machine, and I'm trying to run the example from their site

```
import pdfquery
pdf = pdfquery.PDFQuery("examples/sample.pdf")
pdf.load()
label = pdf.pq(':contains("Your first name and initial")')
left_corner = float(label.attr('x0'))
bottom_corner = float(label.attr('y0'))
name = pdf.pq(':in_bbox("%s, %s, %s, %s")' % (left_corner, bottom_corner-30, left_corner+150, bottom_corner)).text()
print name
```

the problem is that I get this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testePdfQuery.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pdfquery
  File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/pdfquery-0.1.3/pdfquery/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pdfquery import PDFQuery
  File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/pdfquery-0.1.3/pdfquery/pdfquery.py", line 23, in <module>
    cssselect.Function._xpath_in_bbox = _xpath_in_bbox
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Function'
```

any ideas how I can fix this and run the example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of lxml version not supported.

Do the following :

```
1. pip uninstall pdfquery
2. pip install -e git+https://github.com/jcushman/pdfquery.git#egg=pdfquery
```

This should solve the problem.
More details about the issue at : https://github.com/jcushman/pdfquery/issues/6