# ImportError: No module named 'pdfquery'

Tags: python

I install pdfquery in both versions of python 2.x and 3.x but I have the same error when I try to run this code:

```
import pdfquery
pdf = pdfquery.PDFQuery("examples/sample.pdf")
pdf.load()
label = pdf.pq(':contains("Your first name and initial")')
left_corner = float(label.attr('x0'))
bottom_corner = float(label.attr('y0'))
name = pdf.pq(':in_bbox("%s, %s, %s, %s")' % (left_corner, bottom_corner-30, left_corner+150, bottom_corner)).text()
print ('name')
```

This are the error I have in python console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/prueba pdfminer/ejemplo leer pdf.py", line 1, in <module>
import pdfquery
ImportError: No module named 'pdfquery'
```

I search and search unistall and install library and python but can not fix.

I apreciate your help

Comment: How did you try to install it? Which OS are you using?

Comment: possible dupllicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988102/error-trying-to-run-pdfquery-example

Comment: TIP:remove spaces in python file please, ejemplo leer pdf.py NO ejemplo_leer_pdf.py ,at most.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

1. pip uninstall pdfquery
2. pip install -e git+https://github.com/jcushman/pdfquery.git#egg=pdfquery

[More on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988102/error-trying-to-run-pdfquery-example)