# Error on pdfquery module install - invalid syntax

Tags: python

Trying unsuccessfully to install pdfquery on my Win 7 machine, but running into "SyntaxError:  invalid syntax"

Environment: Windows 7, Home Premium, Service Pack 1. Python 3.4.2.

I tried the steps suggested by BigBang at [30845808](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845808/importerror-no-module-named-pdfquery) , but still unable to install.  Here is a screenshot of the error (running CMD shell as Admin)

All suggestions welcome as this module looks very useful (once installed ;-) )

[image]

Comment: that print syntax is python 2, you are running python 3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  I'm embarasssed not to have noticed that.  Got in touch w the author of pdfquery who said, "The package doesn't support Python3 right now, no -- see this bug: https://github.com/jcushman/pdfquery/issues/22

The Python2 print statement appears in the pdfminer library, which is a major dependency for pdfquery. So probably the biggest hurdle is getting pdfminer to support Python3 -- after that, updating pdfquery would be pretty easy."